# responsive website not obeying css percentages

Tags: css, responsive

When we reduce the window size down to below 680px in full screen mode the items all appear in a column.  Since all the css is define in percentages why is this happening?

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:5%;
    text-align:center;
    color:darkblue;
}

.img-container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}

.lround{
    border-top-left-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
}

.rround{
    border-top-right-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
}

.small{
    width:12.5%;
}

#formWrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    width:60%;
    border:solid 1px green;
}

input{
    width:40%;
    margin:2% 4%;
}

input{
    font-size:2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Register</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/header.css">-->

</head>



<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <img src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/swb.png" alt="SwB">

    <div class='img-container'>
      <img class='lround small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-1.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-2.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-3.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-4.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-5.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='rround small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-6.png" alt="img-1">
    </div>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/register.css">-->
    <form>
      <div id='formWrapper'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='first name'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='last name'>
        <input type='tel' placeholder='mobile phone number'>
        <input type='email' placeholder='email'>
        <input type='password' placeholder='password'>
        <input type='password' placeholder='confirm password'>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Inputs have a default min-width which will make them stop shrinking, You can try `<div>` elements to see the difference, They wrap because their border/padding is added to their width after the percentage calculation, Curtsey of  the `border-box` default value `content-box`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the borders of the inputs disappear suddenly you don't have the problem. Borders are in pixels and not in percentages. As you make the screen smaller the borders don't resize but the percentages do.

You can add some `@media` to change the margins of the inputs as you shrink the screen.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:5%;
    text-align:center;
    color:darkblue;
}

.img-container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}

.lround{
    border-top-left-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
}

.rround{
    border-top-right-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
}

.small{
    width:12.5%;
}

#formWrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    width:60%;
    border:solid 1px green;
}

input{
    width:40%;
    margin:2% 4%;
}

input{
    font-size:2vw;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  input{
      margin:2% 3%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  input{
      margin:2% 2%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 300px) {
  input{
      margin:2% 1%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Register</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/header.css">-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <img src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/swb.png" alt="SwB">

    <div class='img-container'>
      <img class='lround small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-1.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-2.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-3.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-4.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-5.png" alt="img-1">
      <img class='rround small' src="https://www.sailwbob.com/images/img-6.png" alt="img-1">
    </div>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/register.css">-->
    <form>
      <div id='formWrapper'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='first name'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='last name'>
        <input type='tel' placeholder='mobile phone number'>
        <input type='email' placeholder='email'>
        <input type='password' placeholder='password'>
        <input type='password' placeholder='confirm password'>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```